# How to hide logs in some tests but not in others?

Tags: unit-testing, logging, elixir, ex-unit

### Background

I have library that logs messages depending on the value of `disable_logging`:

```
unless Application.get(:my_app, :disable_logging, false), do:
  Logger.info("Hello World!")
```

Depending on `MIX_ENV` I have a config for each setup:

```
#test.config
use Mix.Config
config :my_app, disable_logging: true
```

### Problem

The issue here is that I don't want log messages all over my test results. So, naturally, I could set the `disable_logging` to true and be done with it.

However, if I do it, I can't test whether or not the Logger is being called and if it's being called with the correct values:

- https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.CaptureLog.html

### Question

So, given this I have some questions:

1. Is there a way to activate logs but without outputting them to the terminal when I am running tests?
2. Is there a way to only activate logs for some tests in my test suite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare [`ExUnit.setup/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Callbacks.html#setup/1) with a mandatory [`ExUnit.on_exit/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Callbacks.html#on_exit/2) to set the environment variable with [`Application.put_env/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Application.html#put_env/4).

```
setup do
  Application.put_env(:my_app, :disable_logging, false)

  on_exit fn ->
    Application.put_env(:my_app, :disable_logging, true)
  end

  :ok
end
```

I did not test it, but it should work.

Comment: Yes. SO rules explicitly state 1 question per post, so I answered the last one. For the first, use whatever file logger backend and configure your test suits to use it. This behaviour is common across all the environments, it is not tests-specific and has basically nothing in common with the text above.

Answer (score 1):

Why not keep using [`ExUnit.CaptureLog`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.CaptureLog.html) to suppress the logs and just discard the result?

---

If you have a large number of tests that log to console and don't want to do that for all of them, you can create a custom ExUnit `tag`, combined with @Aleksei's answer, that does it for you.

In your `ExUnit.Case` template, add this:

```ex
setup tags do
  if tags[:disable_logger] do
    Application.put_env(:my_app, :disable_logging, false)

    on_exit(fn ->
      Application.put_env(:my_app, :disable_logging, true)
    end)
  end

  :ok
end
```

Now you can just specify the tag for the tests you want logging disabled for:

```ex
@tag disable_logger: true
test "something happens" do
  # ...
end
```

---

***Note:** You will encounter issues with this if you run your tests asynchronously*